# Multi-value XML item to C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have a XML file which has a set of items formatted like this:

```
<MyItems>
   <item size_x="2" size_y="2"/>
   <item value1="0" value2="0"/>
   <item value1="0" value2="0"/>
   <item value1="0" value2="0"/>
   <item value1="0" value2="0"/>
<MyItems/>
```

I'm trying to deserialize this into a 2D array, But i don't know what data type the items translate into in C#.
Are these structs? And if so, How can the first entry in the list have different names for it's values?
And would the formatting be the same if i re-serialize the list from my code?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To be honest, that isn't a great layout of xml for `XmlSerializer` - or just about anything else; I'd have gone with `<MyItems x="2" y="2">` with 4 inner `<item.../>`; you might have to deserialize this manually via `XmlSerializer` / document parsing. How big / complex is the "real" xml?

Comment: Does the XML producer has an xsd file that can share with you? That way you can use xsd.exe or another tool to generate your C# classes

Comment: @RickyStam the schema here isn't hugely helpful, since the layout chosen simply isn't a great idea for... anything

Comment: I am not responsible for the program&code that produces and reads the XML snippet seen above. I simply wish to make a program to modify it on my own terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument XD = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load("URL");
Dictionary<string,string> Data = (from _Mi in XD.Elements("MyItems")
              from _It in _Mi.Elements("item")
              select new
              {
                  V1= n.Attribute("value1").Value,
                  V2= n.Attribute("value2").Value
              }).ToDictionary(c => (string)c.V1, c => (string)c.V2);
```

you can also use

```
V1 = n.FirstAttribute.Value;
V2 = n.LastAttribute.Value;
```

or

```
_values = n.Attributes.tolist();
```

Comment: Is this working on node `<item size_x="2" size_y="2"/>`?